# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined on Windows 2012

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, uncaught-exception

I keeping getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

That is caused by this JavaScript line:

```
top.Main.document.location = Tabpage;
```

I am running Classic ASP on a Windows 2012 Machine.  In IE it crashes the 
IIS Server with no error message, while Chrome gives me error mentioned above.
I have tried `self.Main.document.location.href` and `window.location.href`  and `top.location` with no luck.

It's not using an iframe.  I think that it's not loading Tabpage from the array, as now its just 404 errors.
Here is the entire function:

```
function ShowinMain(Tabfocuspage) {   
     if (loggedin == true) {
     Tabpage = Tabfocuspage + '.asp'; 
     if (Tabfocuspage == 'MyPage') {
     Tabpage = 'page1.asp'; }

     if (Tabfocuspage == 'Reports') {
     Tabpage = 'page2.asp'; }

     if (Tabfocuspage == 'Policy') {
     Tabpage = 'page3.asp'; }

     if (Tabfocuspage == 'System Admin') {
     Tabpage = 'page4.asp'; }

     if (Tabfocuspage == 'Assets') {
     Tabpage = 'page5.asp'; }

     if (Tabfocuspage == 'Help') {
     Tabpage = 'page6.asp'; }

     } else {
     Tabpage = 'login.htm'; 
     }
     initTabs(Tabfocuspage);
     top.Main.location.href = 'Tabpage';
     }
```

Comment: So what is `top.Main` an iframe/frame?

Comment: It's frame and frameset.  I haven't found a easy replacement for  the frameset yet.

Comment: top.Main.location.href? FYI Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Now it's not crashing IIS with Unhandled Exception, but in IE gives 404 error and Chrome Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Comment: How can it crash IIS? Are you sure `Tabpage` is correct value? Is `Main` the name of the iframe? Show the basic frame page's mark up.

Comment: Try not naming your frame "Main", it might be a protected keyword. Alternatively, you might want to try top['Main'].location.href

Comment: <A HREF='#' onClick=" + "\"ShowinMain('" + tabs[i] + "')\"" + "CLASS='" + tabclass + "'>" + tabs[i] + "</A>  This is the line where its not firing from.